# Shortening a string in Perl? (simple)

Tags: perl, string

I have a string:

```
$path = "C:/Users/user1/tools/test_folder/TEST1_HHH.123"
```

How do I get Perl to print just the `TEST1` part of the string?

ADDITION 3/15/11 -

What if instead of TEST1_HHH.123, the file name if TEST1_2_HHH.123 and I want everything before the _HHH.123? That is the only constant that I want to get rid of (and the other part of the path). THanks –

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is simple and portable:

```
use File::Basename qw( basename );
my ($word) = basename($path) =~ /^([^_]+)/;
```

[File::Basename](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aBasename)

Comment: What if instead of TEST1_HHH.123, the file name if TEST1_2_HHH.123 and I want everything before the _HHH.123?  That is the only constant that I want to get rid of (and the other part of the path). THanks

Comment: @dewalla, `/^(.*)_HHH\.123\z/`

Comment: It is only portable if the string is a path on the OS `perl` is running on.  If the your code ran on a Vax with the string `"C:/Users/user1/tools/test_folder/TEST1_HHH.123"` you would not get the results you wanted.

Comment: @Chas. Owens, Yes, that's the definition of portable. I didn't claim it can handle paths from any systems. Path::Class is what you'd want then

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $path =~ /.*\/(([^\/]*)_([^\/]*))$/ )
{ 
  my $file = $1; # TEST1_HHH.123
  my $name = $2; # TEST1
  my $suff = $3; # HHH.123
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my @test='';
my $test1='';
my $path = "C:/Users/user1/tools/test_folder/TEST1_HHH.123";
@test = split('/',$path);
print "@test\n";
my $test1 ="$test[$#test]";
@res = split('_',$test1);
print "$res[0]";
```

Comment: `my @test='';` -- I do not think this does what you think it does. Also, you forgot a semi-colon on line 4.

Comment: As it's a file path, the above is unportable, even within Windows, as the path could as easily be `C:\Foo\Bar\Baz`